# Mat-select is not showing values in angular 2

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am implementing an angular material select. I can get the values from the webapi but for some reason it's not showing in my mat-select. The dropdown has the correct number of rows but the texts are not showing and the value when it is selected too. Please see my code below:

```
<mat-form-field>
  <mat-label>Select property type</mat-label>
  <mat-select [(value)]="selectedPropertyType">
    <mat-option>None</mat-option>
    <mat-option
      *ngFor="let item of propertyTypes"
      [value]="item.PropertyTypeId"
      >{{ item.Type }}</mat-option
    >
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
<p>You selected: {{ selectedPropertyType }}</p>
```

this is how I get the values:

```
getPropertyTypes = () => {
    this.propertyService.getPropertyTypes()
        .subscribe((data: PropertyType[]) => {
            this.propertyTypes = data;
            console.log(this.propertyTypes);
        })
}
```

This is the result I get:
[image]
Can you please show me how to do this right? Thank you.

Comment: are there any errors in your console ? also post your sample data here

Comment: i recommend using safe navigation operator for example `{{ item?.type}} `

Comment: @JoelJoseph That is how it is implemented on angular material "https://material.angular.io/components/select/overview"

Comment: you have error here `{{ item.Type }}` should be `{{ item.type }}`

Comment: remove the capital `T` it should have been  `{{ item?.type}}`

Comment: @Ibanez1408 oh i understand thought it was some typo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a typo in your code, you have used `Type` instead of `type`. Also i recommend you use safe navigation operator  :

```
{{ item?.type}}
```